# Javascript: Overwriting the prototype of a Backbone model

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js, splunk

I want to overwrite the prototype of a Backbone model using underscore.js. This is my code:

```
_.extend(TableView.prototype, {
    el: $("#" + this.id + "_div"),
});
```

In summary, I want that by default the model is attached to a html element with an id equal to the model's id plus "_div". The model's id is `TableView`'s attribute `id`, and I try to access the model using `this`. The problem is that I get the error: "this is undefined". Why?

PS: I know that the correct way is to extend the model in a new one. I want to overwrite the original one because Backbone's extend() method seems to be not like class inheritance, and `my_new_object instanceof TheOldModel` return `false`. Anyway, I get the same error with `TableView.extend()` too.

PPS: I'm extending some Splunk views.

Comment: What are you expecting that `this` will refer to? To an instance of `TableView`? Remember that `this` gets assigned inside a function call, but you are not referring to `this` inside any function (in the example given). **Edit:**: See [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When your code snippet is evaluated, `this` has no specific meaning and is set to whatever the context is. It would only make sense in an instance context which happens way later.

If you want to set a dynamic `el`, provide a function to be evaluated when you instantiate a view:

```
var TableView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: function() {
        return '#'+this.id+'_div';
    }
});

var v = new TableView({id: 'x'});
console.log(v.$el.text());
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/bcfhqq18/

Or, if you prefer to modify the prototype

```
TableView.prototype.el = function() {
    return '#'+this.id+'_div';
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/bcfhqq18/2/

Finally, note that extending a class via Backbone sets the prototype chain and `instanceof` should be true when testing against an ancestor class:

```
var TableView = Backbone.View.extend({
});
var DeepTableView = TableView.extend({
    el: function() {
        return '#'+this.id+'_div';
    }
});

var v = new DeepTableView({id: 'x'});

console.log(v instanceof Backbone.View); // true
console.log(v instanceof TableView); // true
console.log(v instanceof DeepTableView); // true
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/bcfhqq18/3/

Comment: Well, it works, but I'm a bit confused. Why can I replace the attribute `id` with a method? And furthermore, when I create a new `DeepTableView`, I can override the default `el` with a static jQuery element, instead of assigning to it a function. It seems that Javascript doesn't matter if something is a method or if it's an attribute.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your meaning, but defining an attribute of a class view with a value is done when you want the same value for all instances of that class, and with a function when you want a different value for each instance when you instantiate it.

Comment: As to the why it works, it's because Backbone allows the use of those two forms (mostly via http://underscorejs.org/#result)